# Supabase Add additional redirect URL not working

Tags: supabase

I'm trying to set up auth in supabase

Following the tutorial, I try adding domain 'io.supabase.flutterquickstart://login-callback/'

but nothing happens. Maybe this is a bug in the software, not sure[image]

Comment: I'm sorry to hear that you haven't been able to add Redirect URLs. Have you opened your console on the browser to see if there were any error messages? What happens when you press the "Add Domain" button in the popup?

Comment: Open issue on GitHub: https://github.com/supabase/supabase/issues/8070#issuecomment-1206169545

Comment: I tested it on Safari and Google Chrome and it works. 
Can you please test it again after rolled out a patch?

Comment: There was a bug on Supabase's auth server that has now been fixed. Can you try it and see if you are still getting the same bug?

Comment: Same problem for me!

Answer (score 5):

I already commented on the Github issue but for reference here as well:

Maybe a hint because I tripped over this twice now in 3 days. Make sure you have a slash at the end of the URL in the additional Redirect URLs and check the API call sent to supabase to compare.
My problem was that the first localhost address works, but the second doesn't because of the missing slash. If it doesn't find the exact URL, it defaults to the "Site URL" address:

[image]

Comment: To include all variants you can add "*" like this: `http://**127.0.0.1:3000/*/*`

Comment: They mentioned this in their documentation but I didn't understand it all. Your answer really helped me, coz my redirectTo URL I put an extra slash but the one on redirect URL did not have a forward slash at the end. Thanks!!!!

Answer (score 1):

Don't change redirect URLs instead, change site URL with your production URL.
You can go to authentication > under configuration - URL configuration > change the site URL to production URL and it will work for google auth.
I was facing issue in google auth after successful login.
And this works for me...

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZBeOY.png)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue (followed the same tutorial), but i just CTRL+C CTRL+V everything expect the io.supabase.* and created a *custom* one.

But there is an important Line on the `login_page.dart` file.

```dart
  await supabase.auth.signInWithOtp(
        email: _emailController.text,
        emailRedirectTo: kIsWeb ? null : 'io.supabase.flutterquickstart://login-callback/',
      );
```

So if youre facing the same issue, i recommend reading through the code and changing the `emailRedirectTo` to your own value if you changed it.

I havent figured it out for solid 30min because normal Deep-Linking works just fine, but the redirect stuff isnt setup.